# Submit file php soap server

Tags: php, file, soap, server

I am requesting help for an issue that I have. I am trying to submit a file to a server by using php SOAP but when I submit, I have this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap11env:Client.SchemaValidationError] :2:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_ELEMENT_CONTENT: Element '{http://mutalyzer.nl/2.0/services}submitBatchJob': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( {http://mutalyzer.nl/2.0/services}data ). in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngs\submit4.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ngs\submit4.php(31): SoapClient->__call('submitBatchJob', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngs\submit4.php on line 31
```

The WSDL description is the following:

**submitBatchJob type submitBatchJob**

```
data type base64Binary
process - optional, nillable; type string
argument - optional, nillable; type string
email - optional, nillable; type string
```

**submitBatchJobResponse type submitBatchJobResponse**

```
submitBatchJobResult - optional, nillable; type string

<xs:complexType name="submitBatchJob">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="data" type="xs:base64Binary" />
<xs:element name="process" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
<xs:element name="argument" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
<xs:element name="email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Here my php script:

```
<?php
$URL = 'https://mutalyzer.nl/services/?wsdl';
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mutalyzer SOAP client</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Mutalyzer SOAP client</h1>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data']) {

    $variant = $_GET['data'];


    $_FILES['data']['name']=$_GET['data'];
    $filename = basename( $_FILES['data']['name']);
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    $handle = fread($file,filesize($filename));
    $data = base64_encode($handle);


    $NameChecker=$_GET['process'];
    echo '<h2>Result for '.htmlentities($variant).'</h2>';

   $options = array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);

    $client = new SoapClient($URL);

    $result = $client->submitBatchJob($data, $NameChecker)
                  ->submitBatchJobResult;


print_r($result); 
}

?>

<h2>Submit job data file to MUTALYZER</h2>

<form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
Input file:
</p>
<input name="data" type="file" id="data" />
<br/>
  Process :
<input type="text" size="10" name="process" id="process" value="NameChecker"/>
<br/>
  <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to correct my script ?
Many Thanks.

Comment: Did you see their sample PHP client? https://mutalyzer.nl/downloads/client-php.php

Comment: @mkaatman, yes I have already checked it out their PHP client. At the beginning, I did something inspired from their php client. But, the array takes only the last row of my data file. WDSL stating data must be base64Binary so that's why I changed the source code.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to catch that exception, with:

```
 try {
   # some code here that causes a problem, hint: soap11env:Client.SchemaValidationError
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Second, it's telling you where the error is:

```
Element '{http://mutalyzer.nl/2.0/services}submitBatchJob': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( {http://mutalyzer.nl/2.0/services}data ).
```

and also:

```
in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngs\submit4.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ngs\submit4.php(31): SoapClient->__call('submitBatchJob', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ngs\submit4.php on line 31
```

Comment: I added the exception, I have this error: `:2:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_ELEMENT_CONTENT: Element '{http://mutalyzer.nl/2.0/services}submitBatchJob': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( {http://mutalyzer.nl/2.0/services}data ).` But I don't understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: I also tried to do like this, but it takes only the last line of my csv file:`$options = array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS);
 
    $client = new SoapClient($URL, $options);
$data=array();
while(! feof($handle)){
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 0);
         
    $result = $client->submitBatchJob(array('data' => $data[0], 'process' =>$NameChecker))
                  ->submitBatchJobResult;
               print_r(array('data' => $data, 'process' =>$NameChecker));
            } `

Comment: I haven't had time to read through the docs, but looks like the soap server is expecting some base64Binary code `https://mutalyzer.nl/soap-api#op.submitBatchJob` and you're submitting an array. If it accepts the array, it's asking for some children, so perhaps your array needs to be multidimensional?

Comment: thx for ur reply. I found a solution. I did like that: `$handle = fread($file,filesize($filename));
    $data=array(); 
 $data = $handle;` it works :)